Exposición de microfront en contenedores a travez de Api management
Estoy desarrollando componentes de microfront, estos deben implementarse como contenedores. Estoy usando AKS para implementar estos contenedores, la exposición de estos microfront lo estoy haciendo vía un servicio loadbalancer en AKS. Mi pregunta es si puedo usar API Management en Azure para gobernar el consumo de estos microfront, por favor si me pudieran orientar o consultar documentación para ver si esto es posible o decirme cómo se maneja esta exposición de microfront desplegados como contenedores.
Muchas gracias.
Intenté exponer los microfrontales en API Management, pero no podré consumirlos.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Puntualmente quiero saber si API Management permite exponer un microfront desde AKS, el cual entregue contenido HTML, JS, CSS:
